# .net 4 Application running a .net 2.0 assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a .net 4 Application which needs to use a 3rd Party application in .net 2.0. Running it in .net 4 is causing some exceptions.

Is it possible to force only the assembly be executed in .net 2?

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes.  You can set the Net version is the project settings.  The problem could be also the project needs to be compiled in x86 mode.

Comment: Sorry, maybe that was a bit missunderstanding. I need to run the application in .net 4. only the assembly needs to be running in .net 2.0. I have no possibility to run all under .net 2.0 because there are too much other dependencies to .net 4.

Comment: See following : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called mixed-mode, and you can do it by setting/changing some properties in app.config file, eg.:

```xml
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/> 
</startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding following XML to your configuration file.

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

> Starting with .NET 4, you don't have to worry about compatibility
>   issues at all! Version 4 introduced a new feature called "In-Process
>   Side-by-Side Execution", which essentially allows you to load multiple
>   versions of the CLR into the same process.
>   In other words, since your main application is running on the 4.0
>   runtime, you can tell it to load the 2.0 runtime when you load the 2.0
>   CLR assembly. The 2.0 CLR assembly will use the 2.0 runtime, while
>   your application will continue to use the 4.0 runtime.

You can find more details from the links below:

[When linking a .NET 2.0 Managed Assembly from a .NET 4.0 Application, which framework is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267491/when-linking-a-net-2-0-managed-assembly-from-a-net-4-0-application-which-fram)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68(v=vs.110).aspx